# Solving helper rewrite conflict. Three modules conflicted on payment/data helper.

Tags: magento-1.9, helper, conflict, magerun

I have a problem where a newly installed module is not working due to a conflict.

The result of n98-magerun `dev:module:rewrite:conflicts`:

[image: module conflict]

How would I solve this problem? Is there any particular way of re-writting those classes?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15848/how-to-use-multiple-module-dependencies

Comment: You can use <depends> in magento 1.9

Comment: thanks for suggestion! I managed to get it fixed using different method, however, your tip seems to be correct! Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it fixed by using if condition and chaining them together.

---

I left the **Amasty_Methods** to extend core class

> app/code/local/Amasty/Methods/Helper/Payment/Data.php

```
class Amasty_Methods_Helper_Payment_Data extends Mage_Payment_Helper_Data
{
```

Then edited the other Amasty module called Amasty_Payrestriction to extend the Amasty_Methods (Or core class if they module is disabled)

> app/code/local/Amasty/Payrestriction/Helper/Payment/Data.php

```
if (Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('Amasty_Methods')) {
  class Amasty_Payrestriction_Helper_Payment_Data_Temp extends Amasty_Methods_Helper_Payment_Data {}
}
else {
  class Amasty_Payrestriction_Helper_Payment_Data_Temp extends Mage_Payment_Helper_Data {}
}

class Amasty_Payrestriction_Helper_Payment_Data extends Amasty_Payrestriction_Helper_Payment_Data_Temp
{
```

At last, I edited the SagePay module to extend the `Amasty_Payrestriction` class or core class if this is disabled.

> app/code/local/Ebizmarts/SagePaySuite/Helper/Payment/Data.php

```
if (Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('Amasty_Payrestriction')) {
    class Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Helper_Payment_Data_Temp extends Amasty_Payrestriction_Helper_Payment_Data {}
}  
else {
    class Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Helper_Payment_Data_Temp extends Mage_Payment_Helper_Data {}
}

class Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Helper_Payment_Data extends Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Helper_Payment_Data_Temp {
```

---

### Conclusion:

At the end, all I did was extending each class in following pattern:

**Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite -> Amasty_Payrestriction -> Amasty_Methods -> Mage_Payment_Helper_Data**

if any of the modules are disabled or removed, the chain will not break due to the if condition.

I hope someone will find this useful!

Answer (score 1):

Amasty has a great tool on fixing conflicts on rewrites, and provide the code for that after [Link](https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/how-to-fix-3rd-party-extension-conflicts.html) :

- Go to

> Admin panel -> System -> Amasty Extensions -> Extensions &
>   Notifications -> Troubleshooter

- Look for the conflicts that relate to Amasty conflicting extension and click Fix.
- Flush the cache, and check the performance. In case a problem remains and the extension is not working, click Rollback and try out other offered solutions.

Comment: I tried using this tool, it didn't work tho. Magerun was still showing a conflict :/

Comment: Try to change the helper path after extends or make modifications to the config xml rewrite tag.

Comment: I managed to solve my problem! See my answer. Although, thank you for your interest. +1 from me.

Comment: Glad you fixed that sir.